# Setting image on ImageView on click event

Tags: android, android-imageview, onitemclicklistener

I have the following code:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            img.setImageBitmap(randomArray.get(position).getImage());
            pairList.add(img);
            positions.add(position);
            turned++;

            if(turned == 2){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if(randomArray.get(positions.get(0)).getName().equals(randomArray.get(positions.get(1)).getName())){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You guessed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    pairList.get(0).setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back_card));
                    pairList.get(1).setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back_card));
                }
                pairList.clear();
                positions.clear();
                turned = 0;
                return;
            }
        }
    });
```

The behavoiur I expect is this : the user clicks an imageView  item, and the item changes the image. Initially I have a card and the user sees its back image, after click, he sees the front image. At the second card, the same. But if the cards are pair, I want them to remain turned, otherwise they show the back image again. The problem is that the image doesn't appear until the method returns. So, if the card are not pair, the user doesn't see the second card, because they turn immediately. I don't understand why the image is not set right after this line:

```
img.setImageBitmap(randomArray.get(position).getImage());
```

but at the end of method. I hope I made myself clear, thanks for your help!

Comment: How can you be sure **when** exactly the image is set? It might take some time to replace the Image and that delay might look like it's replacing it later to you

Comment: I used the debuger and I noticed that the image is set on UI only after exiting the method. The problem remains the same without the delay, which I used to let the time to the user to see the card....